# Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected element type 'NSLayoutConstraint'

Tags: swift

I followed a YouTube tutorial on creating a dropdown list in Swift.
I encountered an error which I can't fix, I looked here in Stackoverflow and on search results from Google but nothing worked for me.
This is the problem I get:

> Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected element type 'NSLayoutConstraint'

This is the code:

```
class Dropdown: UIButton, DropDownProtocol {
    var dropView = DropDownView()
    var height = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var isOpen = false

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.appBlack
        dropView = DropDownView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        dropView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dropView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        self.superview?.addSubview(dropView)
        self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(dropView) //Needed?

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            dropView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
            dropView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            dropView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor),
            height = (dropView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)) <--- problem occurs here
        ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to assign a value to `height` inside the call to `activate`.

Refactor just a bit:

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    self.superview?.addSubview(dropView)
    self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(dropView) //Needed?

    height = dropView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        dropView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
        dropView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
        dropView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor),
        height
    ])
}
```